# Reduce initial loading time of Angular 7 Application

Tags: angular

When i run my application after clearing cookie,cache of browser then the main.js(1.11 MB) takes time (6-7S) to get content download of application.

How can i reduce initial loading time?

Comment: Your question is really broad, anyway you should avoid to load every module of your application from start. Try  to modularize your app and load every module/feature in lazy mode. All the best

Comment: You upgrade to Angular 8 and enable [Ivy](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

Comment: g-zip, cdn could help